# what is the correct syntax for defining a static (non-inherited) method on an interface in jdk 8?

Tags: java, static, java-8

The syntax (in jdk 8) for virtual extension methods/aka default overrridable methods is well documented :

```
 public interface Foo {
      default void bar(String out) {
          System.out.println(out);
      };
    }
```

But I can't find any reference for the correct syntax for **static non-inherited methods on interfaces**  ?

Comment: this may help http://www.javabeat.net/2012/05/virtual-extension-methods-in-java-8/

Comment: I haven't heard of any new feature like this. It doesn't sound right. What would be the point of an interface's having a non-inherited method?

Comment: @RyanStewart you can not override it, but you can run it.

Comment: It just sounds like a weird feature, and I'm curious about it. Can you point me at any kind of info on it?

Comment: @RyanStewart lol, I can't find nuthin. Spent a fair bit of time googling, but fail to find any docs. My original source is an off the cuff tweet. But I have got it compiling using the syntax in the answer, and by making sue I am using jdk lambda. If yo find any more  info I woul dbe itnerested too.

Comment: But where did you even learn about the feature? What's its intended use?

Comment: [Found them on twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=interface%20static%20method&src=typd) for other interested parties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is the same as if the method was in a class:

```
public static void bar() {
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

Comment: I get an error compiling that ... is there a super special jdk 8 I need ?

Comment: I'm using the b74 binary downloaded from http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/, and it compiles fine. They're at b75 now.

Comment: ok thanks, I was using he non lambda version. Although the documentation for this feature is still rather sparse -  I can't find any.

Comment: how do you execute these ... I have tried multple ways with no luck, or are they not implemented properly yet

Comment: Just like any other static method : `Foo.bar()`. Are you using the lambda-enabled JDK, downloadable from the link I gave 4 comments above?