# concrete methods in interfaces Java1.8

Tags: java, interface

During a discussion one of my friend tell me that `concrete methods would be allowed in java 1.8 in interfaces` then at that time a question came into my mind i-e If they are allowed then How will we distinguish the methods.For example
I have two Interface `Animal.java` and `Pet.java` and both have same concrete method i-e `eat()`

```
   public interfaces Animal{

        void eat(){
                System.out.println("Animal Start eating ....");
        }
   }

   public interfaces Pet{

        void eat(){
                System.out.println("Pet Start eating ....");
        }
   }
```

Now my `Zoo.java` implement both of these and didn't override

```
    public class Zoo() implements Pet , Animal{ 
             //Now name method is a part of this class
   }
```

Now here is my confusion.How can I call a specific method on inteface `animal` using `Test` object

```
public class Demo{
        public static void main(String[] args){

                 Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
                 zoo.eat();    //What would be the output
        }
 }
```

Any suggestions? or is there any solution for this in java1.8 as I am unable to find its answer.

Comment: but I didn't find this answers in these question.If it is a duplicate then please guide me regarding this issue resolvation

Comment: this might be of itnerest too, static non-inherited methods in interfaces http://stackoverflow.com/q/14646027/106261

Comment: your original question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7857884/106261

Comment: @NimChimpsky may be its my bad but still i am not able to find (1)what would be the output of `zoo.eat();` and (2) How can I call the interface specific method?

Comment: @freak yoru syntax is wrong btw I will try it out usign jdk 8, give me 5 mins

Comment: @NimChimpsky ok yes I also want to know is there any syntax changing or what would be the real syntax for this method calling.by the way thanks :)

Comment: I've attempted to answer your question to your very good and specific question with an example. Please follow the link: stackoverflow.com/q/14646027/106261and

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get a compile time error, unless you override eat in your Zoo class.

```
java: class defaultMethods.Zoo inherits unrelated defaults for eat() from types Pet and Animal
```

The latest and geatest jdk is [here btw](http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/). And the syntax should be

```
default void eat(){
  System.out.println("Animal Start eating ....");
}
```

Comment: great :) so in this case both methods(from Animal & Pet) get updated? right?

Comment: not updated, overrridden

Comment: one last thing , It means if we have default concrete methods with same name then we should override default method? otherwise it is a compile time error?right?